# How to solve mismatch in train and test set after categorical encoding?

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I have many categorical variables which exist in my test set but don't in my train set. They are important so I can't drop them. Should I combine train and test set or what other solution should I make?

Answer (score 0):

You have some options in this case, you can use another technique than Holdout to separate your data like a [K-Fold Cross-validation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html) or [Leave-one-out](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.LeaveOneOut.html).

When using a holdout is necessary to stratify your data to all subsets have all classes on train/test/validation subset's and **NEVER** use your test or validation dataset to fit your model, when you do it the model will learn this data and you probably will be overfitting your model, read more about it [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_underfitting_overfitting.html)

Answer (score -1):

How did you end up in this situation? Normally you take a dataset and divide it into two subsets.  The first subset is used to fit the model and is referred to as the training dataset. The second subset is not used to train the model; instead, the input element of the dataset is provided to the model, then predictions are made and compared to the expected values. This second dataset is referred to as the test dataset.

But it is clear that, because they originate from the same original dataset, that they both have the same categorical variables.